# My sql schema design issues - general design

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I am trying to design my database. for now my schema is as below:

[image]

There exist 3 fixed tables already and during time the numbers of my tables will be increasing with the same fields but different values in tables  (mm, xx, yy, zz,...). There is not any duplication between each table.

a) `user` table, who are the internal users.

b) `map_platform_user`, which mapped the internal users with the external users. Internal users are our users and external users are our partner users.

c) `platform`, is a partners' platforms.

d) `mm` or `xx`, is the user information that are difference for each platforms.

I have created the look up table called `map_platform_user`. This table have a field `user_platform_id` that I though to create a relation with the `mm` table. (PK-FK).

1) I though to create a multiple references like `mm_user_id(PK), xx_user_id(PK),...` to the `user_platform_id (PK)`. However I am pretty sure that this solution is wrong and I can not have several references to one table.

2) My next solution is to create each time a `new field` to the table `map_platform_user` such as `user_platform_id1`, `user_platform_id2`,... but this solution requires altering each time the table `map_platform_user`.

3) The third solution I thought about that is to not create the extra tables and store everything in the `map_platform_user` table, so if the new platforms are coming based on our demands, I store them in the field `user_platform_id`. In this case I have to add `name,email,..` to the table `map_platform_user`.

I would like to mention that the `user_platform_id` is an `external_id` which should be received from our clients.

The version of mysql is `5.5.47`and the engine in `InnoDB`. I will be appreciated for any solution and discussion in order to improve the performance of my db. I will have a big amount of data.

Comment: Why are you adding multiple tables with the same structure (`mm` and `xx`)?

Comment: @MarkBannister, they are our clients and we need these fields name,email,.. from them, so the columns are the same but not the values. I have put them there as an example to show that I will have such a repetitive structure during time.

Comment: Why don;t you add a `type` field to the customer table, representing `mm`, `xx`, `whatever`?.

Comment: @Ben platform table in fact is the name of our customers and I have it already. I called it platform

Comment: If you are having (or expect to have) performance problems, please show us the query/queries that are slow.

Comment: @RickJames I have started to design and I am not sure about query, I am starting to learn how can I improve the performance. As I understood from your point, this should be a next step after design the schema, right?

Comment: Formulating the `SELECTs` gives you insight in to indexes, `JOINs`, etc.  Your `Map_platform_user` looks like a many-to-many mapping table.  See [my tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on writing such.

Comment: @RickJames it is one-many mapping. 1 user can have several map with external id, also one platform can have several map too.

Comment: 1:Many does not need an extra table.  You store the link (and timestamp) on the 'many' side.